# Error : No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android-studio

I am a beginner in java android studio, I am trying to retrieve my data from the mysql database using recycleview but I am encountering an error No adapter attached; skipping layout in the logcast if anyone can help me. THANKS

```
package ne.aes.iat;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2/iat/get.php";

    

    List<Etudiant> etudiantList;

    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recylcerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //initializing the etutiantList
        etudiantList = new ArrayList<>();

        //this method will fetch and parse json
        //to display it in recyclerview
        chargerEtudiants();

        /*nomET = findViewById(R.id.nom);
        prenomET = findViewById(R.id.prenom);
        emailET = findViewById(R.id.email);
        telET = findViewById(R.id.tel);*/
    }

    private void chargerEtudiants() {

        /*
         * Creating a String Request
         * The request type is GET defined by first parameter
         * The URL is defined in the second parameter
         * Then we have a Response Listener and a Error Listener
         * In response listener we will get the JSON response as a String
         * */
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject etudiant = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                //adding the product to product list
                                etudiantList.add(new Etudiant(
                                        etudiant.getInt("id"),
                                        etudiant.getString("prenom"),
                                        etudiant.getString("nom"),
                                        etudiant.getString("email"),
                                        etudiant.getString("tel"),
                                        etudiant.getString("image")
                                ));
                            }

                            //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                            Adapter adapter = new Adapter(MainActivity.this, etudiantList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }

   }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:id="@+id/recylcerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="745dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-51dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[recyclerview No adapter attached; skipping layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout)